# Excel SUBSTITUTE replacing both exact and contains word as well

Tags: excel, excel-formula, replace

how to replace the word only if exact match found in a paragraph

[image]

`LAMBDA` is not supporting in our system, any solution for it

`=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,D2,E2),D3,E3),D4,E4),D6,E6),D6,E6),D5,E5),D7,E7),D8,E8),D9,E9),D10,E10),D11,E11),D12,E12),D13,E13),D14,E14),D15,E15),D16,E16),D17,E17))`

above formual currenlty i am using it

Comment: What is your current Excel version?

Comment: May be you could try this : `=LET(
α,TEXTSPLIT(A2,," "),
TEXTJOIN(" ",,IFERROR(XLOOKUP(α,$D$2:$D$17,$E$2:$E$17,α),"")))`

Comment: Or may be this `=LET(α,FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b"),
TEXTJOIN(" ",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(α,$D$2:$E$17,2,0),α)))`

Comment: Thanks.. @MayukhBhattacharya, It works, but my applicable only support these excel function, Please see the link, If you know if we can achieve it by using any of these excel function  https://docs.aspose.com/cells/net/supported-formula-functions/#x

Comment: @SaravananBaskar what is your Excel Version may I know please.

Comment: You could try this and let me know : `=TEXTJOIN(" ",1,
XLOOKUP(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",REPT(" ",100)),SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",))+1)*100-99,100)),$D$2:$D$17,$E$2:$E$17,
TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",REPT(" ",100)),SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",))+1)*100-99,100))))`